# How can I use "Only show when" on adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have tried to search many places but I don't see any doc talk about how to use it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTkM5.png

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more of your card, I think you need to remove the second `$`. Here's a very simple example:

**Card:**

```json
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "${title}",
            "$when": "${showTitle == true}"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3"
}
```

**Data:**

```json
{
    "title": "This is a title",
    "showTitle": true
}
```

If you change `showTitle` to false in the data, the text will no longer show.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to use 'if not' logic, here is the example

```
"$when": "${$root.variableName != \"test\"}"
```

The block will show if the value is not "test"